# Creating an interactive map - collect group of pixel coordinates from specific region of an image

Tags: image-processing, pixel, imagemap

I need to pick certain regions on an image. Then I want to store this data in an xml file.

My purpose is to create an interactive map. For example, if a user clicks on a certain point on the image, the application will search what pixel range the user selected and then give appropriate information back to the user.

I was attempting to see if I could select regions of an image through photo editing software and see if I can grab the pixel range for the selected region. I am using Pixelmator and could not find much. I am not the most experienced user of such software and image processing.

I want this data to apply to an application developed in HTML5 and Javascript. No server side dependencies.

The images I am working with will be jpeg, gif, or png.

Any ideas on how to approach this is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

OK I think you are developing with amMap :)

Take a look at OpenCV. With it, you can extract all the regions in your image map. Doc. example is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html). Don't forget pre-processing steps like blurring, canny edge detection; as they are used in the tutorial.

Take pixel coordinate of the image with some sort of click event handler. Then use [pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpoly#cv.PointPolygonTest) to see which blob this pixel is belong to.

I think thats what you asked for.

Comment: I am just looking into it, thanks for the suggestion. I will get back to you